# Yii2 Model Rules Update Checking Rules For Same Record

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I.E. If i update address_line1 then its giving error for mobile number allocated.
While update it should not match with it self.
Even if i change mobile number it should check with other user.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
                    [['mobile_number','address_line1','address_line2','city','state','country','pincode' ],'required'],
                    ['mobile_number','mobile_number_allocation_validate'],

        ];
    }

public function mobile_number_allocation_validate($attribute){
        // add custom validation
        $result = User::find()
        ->where('`mobile_number` = "'.$this->$attribute.'" AND 
                `status` = "A" ')->all();
        if(!empty($result)){
            $this->addError($attribute,'Mobile number is allocated to other vehicle');
        }

    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there a reason you've not just used the `unique` validator?

Comment: @JoeMiller  duplication will be there but i need to filter with active user.as i will not delete my single row from database.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition as :-- Override `beforeSave()` of `User ActiveRecord`

```
/**
 * BeforeSave() check if User ActiveRecord is created with same calculator param
 * if created then return false with model error
 *
 */
public function beforeSave($insert){
    $model = self::find()->where('`mobile_number` = "'.$this->$attribute.'" AND 
            `status` = "A" ')->all();

    if($model !== null && $model->id !== $this->id){
        $this->addError('mobile_number' , 'Mobile number is allocated to other vehicle');
        return false;
    }

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Comment: $this->id  which id will refer ? (Trying to get property of non-object)

Comment: want to know above model is User ActiveRecord Class of any other model class.. other than User Class

Comment: please post your `mobile_number_allocation_validate` function whole class

Comment: from rule i am calling mobile_number_allocation_validate method

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `unique` validator for this, by simply adding a [filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html#$filter-detail) condition like this

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['mobile_number','address_line1','address_line2','city','state','country','pincode' ],'required'],
            ['mobile_number','unique', 'filter' => ['status' => 'A']],
        ];
    }
```